# List files that is changed/modified today by single user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to list all files that is changed(modified) today from single users.

I tried this: `find -mtime -1` but output is wrong. Can you guys/girls please tell me is there a way to list all files that is chanfed today from single user?

Comment: what does "modified from single users" mean?

Comment: list modifed files that is changed by one user i.e. you have serveral users and I want to show modifed files for each of them separately (not togethr)...

Comment: That's simply not possible in general, the id of the last user who modified a file is not usually saved.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -mtime -1 -printf "%u %p\n" | sort
```

will recursively list all files (and the owner's name) in the current directory -- grouped by owner -- that have been modified today.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to group by the owner of the file, you could add `-user $user` and loop over all relevant users. if you want to group by the user modifying the file, that is not possible as this information is not stored in the filesystem or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Though not the best solution, but this script can be used.

```
# Check for files modified within past 24 hrs.

modifiedfiles=`find . -mtime -0`
username=`pwd | cut -d'/' -f2` # pwd is your current directory /home/user/

for i in $modifiedfiles
  do 
    check=`grep  $i /home/user/.bash_history`
      if [ "$check" != " " ] 
      then 
        echo "file $i modified by $username "
      fi
  done
```

where **user in path /home/user** is a particular user.
**.bash_history** file contents are compared with the **modifiedfiles** list.